# Random StringByReplacingOccurances of string error that occurs in simulator only

Tags: xcode, exception, void

So I have this strange error. I was able to debug my app without any trouble all day but suddenly this weired error message occured even though I didn't change anything...

2013-04-21 01:06:26.617 Schema REVAMP[4874:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3131f2a3 0x38fc497f 0x3131f1c5 0x31b8c9b5 0x31b8c95d 0x6765 0x58c3 0x3318e311 0x3319a79b 0x3319a4c1 0x3316b4e9 0x3312a803 0x32ed4d8b 0x32ed4929 0x32f037cf 0x331d40e9 0x331d32d5 0x331d24a7 0x331d2431 0x33308309 0x33190691 0x331903d5 0x3318fd3b 0x33186eab 0x33182aed 0x331c41e9 0x3318783f 0x3317f84b 0x33127c39 0x331276cd 0x3312711b 0x34e2a5a3 0x34e2a1d3 0x312f4173 0x312f4117 0x312f2f99 0x31265ebd 0x31265d49 0x3317e485 0x3317b301 0x54cd 0x393fbb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

My void in which the error occurs:

```
- (void) loadSchema {

    NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://schemaappen.se/plist/risbergska.plist"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
    if (data)
        NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ingen internetanslutning" message:@"Försök igen senare" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okej" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }


    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *string = [f stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    unique = string;

    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"måndag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Monday"]) {
        dagen = @"1";
    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"tisdag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"]) {
        dagen = @"2";

    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"onsdag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Wednesday"]) {
        dagen = @"4";
    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"torsdag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Thursday"]) {
        dagen = @"8";
    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"fredag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Friday"]) {
        dagen = @"16";
    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"lördag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Saturday"]) {
        dagen = @"1";
    }
    if ([unique isEqualToString:@"söndag"] || [unique isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {
        dagen = @"1";
    }


    urlString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SchemaURL"];


    NSRange rangeValue = [urlString rangeOfString:@"currentweek" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (rangeValue.length > 0){
        weekURL = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"currentweek" withString:weekNumber];
    }
    else {
        weekURL = urlString;
    }

    NSString *dayURL = [weekURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"dagen" withString:dagen];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dayURL];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:req];

    [MBHUDView hudWithBody:@"Laddar schema..." type:MBAlertViewHUDTypeActivityIndicator hidesAfter:NO show:YES];

}
```

If I run the app on my device without running it through xcode the app works fine. Not a single crash.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason for an app crashing in the simulator, but not on device is case sensitive accessing of files.(Simulator is case sensitive, device is not)

1) I would check any filename accessed being used by **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** for case sensitivity problems.

2) Based on your code and the given error, my first guess would be that **weakNumber** is nil at some point causing the crash.